# Using an AAR SDK file in react native

Tags: java, android, react-native, aar

I'm trying to import an AAR file into a react native project, but having some confusion on what to do. Here is what I did so far:

1. Create a libs folder under android/app
2. Import the .aar file into that libs folder

That's all I got after reading multiple articles and each of a slight difference of what they do after that.

Any help is appreciated. I eventually want to call functions in this AAR file in a react native component.

Comment: You're going to have to do a lot of work to get it there.  You now have a library of Java functions.  To call them from react native, you're going to have to make a native module to make them available to Javascript.  Its going to be a lot of boilerplate code exposing every function you want to be able to call.  I'd really suggest that you try to not do this and find a javascript library that does what you want instead, interacting between Java and react native is a pain.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the android native module doc.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android
briefly,
1.create android XXModule.java and XXPackage.java at android/app.
2.export native functions or arguments to rn.
3.create react native component at src/, use native functions or arguments.